# How to run executable in my Flutter desktop app

Tags: flutter

I want to call the executable file at startup in flutter development desktop application

Comment: please provide more information regarding what the executable is and what exactly you need to do.

Comment: I want to execute the packaged go executable file in flutter. It is an api service that can access data through local api, display the corresponding interface and be able to apply APPStore online